# Continuous error bar plot with relplot() using multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have spectral data of the same substance loaded into a pandas DataFrame which looks something like this (there are 20 experiments and the wave numbers reach to 2300):

```py
    experiment       0      1      2      3      4
    wave number
    400          358.0  307.1  242.6  364.4  308.2
    401          378.9  328.6  283.7  353.3  319.2
    402          402.4  351.4  320.4  347.6  329.8
    403          434.8  379.1  339.7  362.4  338.8
    404          477.1  412.1  339.7  400.4  345.9
    405          522.0  446.7  334.1  444.9  352.6    ...
    ...
```

I have already implemented a rough but working version of this by calculating the mean and values for the error bars manually and using the matplotlib plt.errorbar() function. It looks like this (with the above data):

[image]

But I think this looks rather ugly so I want to use seaborn. I want to have a plot which look like [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/relational.html#aggregation-and-representing-uncertainty).

seaborn.relplot() seems to be able to calculate and plot exactly what I want (as the above link shows) but since my data structure is different than what they use in their tutorial I really don't know how I should go about this.

Comment: Is your dataframe multiindexed with `experiment` and `wave number` as index? **EDIT**: Or is `wave number` just an empty row?

Comment: No, the dataframe has the wave numbers as indices and the individual experiments are stored as rows. "wave number" seems to be the name of the indices. Edit: `df.iloc[0,0]` gives me `358.0` so it doesn't seem to be a row.

Comment: Alright, I think that suggests that it's multiindexed. So we need to transform your data a bit to make it work with the seaborn function. Hang on, I'll add an answer and you can see if it works (it's a bit too long for a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your DF is multiindexed, it should look something like this:

```
                            0      1      2      3      4
experiment wave_number
0          400          358.0  307.1  242.6  364.4  308.2
1          401          378.9  328.6  283.7  353.3  319.2
2          402          402.4  351.4  320.4  347.6  329.8
3          403          434.8  379.1  339.7  362.4  338.8
4          404          477.1  412.1  339.7  400.4  345.9
5          405          522.0  446.7  334.1  444.9  352.6
```

where `experiment` and `wave_number` are indexes. We'll first need to move those to columns, using `df.reset_index()`. It should now look like this:

```
df = df.reset_index()

   experiment  wave_number      0      1      2      3      4
0           0          400  358.0  307.1  242.6  364.4  308.2
1           1          401  378.9  328.6  283.7  353.3  319.2
2           2          402  402.4  351.4  320.4  347.6  329.8
3           3          403  434.8  379.1  339.7  362.4  338.8
4           4          404  477.1  412.1  339.7  400.4  345.9
5           5          405  522.0  446.7  334.1  444.9  352.6
```

We then need to melt this DF to produce multiple rows, with combinations of `experiment` and `wave_number`. We can use `df.melt()` for that:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=["experiment", "wave_number"], value_vars=["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"], var_name="measurement_number", value_name="measured_value")
```

It should now look something like this:

```
df.sort_values(by=["wave_number", "measurement_number"])

    experiment  wave_number measurement_number measured_value
0            0          400                  0          358.0
6            0          400                  1          307.1
12           0          400                  2          242.6
18           0          400                  3          364.4
24           0          400                  4          308.2
1            1          401                  0          378.9
7            1          401                  1          328.6
13           1          401                  2          283.7
19           1          401                  3          353.3
25           1          401                  4          319.2
2            2          402                  0          402.4
8            2          402                  1          351.4
14           2          402                  2          320.4
20           2          402                  3          347.6
26           2          402                  4          329.8
3            3          403                  0          434.8
9            3          403                  1          379.1
15           3          403                  2          339.7
21           3          403                  3          362.4
27           3          403                  4          338.8
4            4          404                  0          477.1
10           4          404                  1          412.1
16           4          404                  2          339.7
22           4          404                  3          400.4
28           4          404                  4          345.9
5            5          405                  0          522.0
11           5          405                  1          446.7
17           5          405                  2          334.1
23           5          405                  3          444.9
29           5          405                  4          352.6
```

My `measured_value` columns was strings for some reason, so I transform them to floats:

```
df.measured_value = df.measured_value.astype(float)
```

Now it's pretty straight-forward to draw the seaborn plot:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.relplot(x="wave_number", y="measured_value", kind="line", data=df)
plt.show()
```

Which gives this:

[image: Resulting plot]